# Difference between on hold and closed question

Tags: discussion, support

Can someone explain to me what is the difference between a question put "On hold" and one that is "Closed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

> Why are some questions marked "on hold"? Questions that need
>   additional work or that are not a good fit for this site may be put on
>   hold by experienced community members. While questions are on hold,
>   they cannot be answered, but can be edited to make them eligible for
>   reopening.
>
> Questions that are edited within five days of being put on hold are
>   automatically added to a reopening queue for community review.
>   Questions that are not reopened within five days will change from [on
>   hold] to [closed].

So it seems question that are flagged go into onhold for clarification and then after 5 days go to closed.

I am sure Mods can close directly and it appears that some reasons for closing question go to on hold and some go to closed. Unless I am writing this on a Monday morning in which case all this could be part of the Garfield Effect.

Comment: Thanks. I searched for an answer to this on SO, but it seams that the week-end killed my search skills.

Comment: @Marius weekends are fine for me, but Mondays are normally terrible so I am surprised I found this today :) http://sphotos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t1.0-9/538061_10151430389520847_1063128657_n.png

Answer (score 3):

"Closed" and "On hold" are the exact same thing in all ways except one: in the first five days a question is closed, we write "on hold" instead of "closed." For the full backstory, see  [I propose changing the term "closed" out for... something else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70061/i-propose-changing-the-term-closed-out-for-something-else) and [Every "close" has its thorn: replace "close" with "on hold" for the first five days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-replace-close-with-on-hold-for-the-first-five-d) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Also note that the help center page that David linked from SO has an equivalent on this site: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions